# Applicability of request verb for items one expects

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, difference

I read the post "Degree of demand with different translations for “request” (noun)" and though I made some progress applying the noun clarifications to their verb forms, the spectrum category I need is not there. I need "asking/having asked to receive a [specific noun] from someone".

- Ich schicke Ihnen die gewünschte Unterlagen/Informationen.
- Ich schicke Ihnen die verlangte Unterlagen/Informationen.
- Ich schicke Ihnen die gebetene Unterlagen/Informationen.
- Ich schicke Ihnen die geforderte Unterlagen/Informationen.
- Ich schicke Ihnen die aufgeforderte Unterlagen/Informationen.
- Ich schicke Ihnen die erforderte Unterlagen/Informationen.

Or is it better use a verb and say,

> Ich schicke Ihnen die Unterlagen/Informationen, die Sie [requested] haben.

I am struggling to find an explanation of the nuances of "requesting" verbs that makes sense to me. Dictionaries either don't clarify or give clear examples that I can connect to my situation. I know there is a tone of importance or urgency as well as formality. Are these examples interchangeable? Rude or otherwise negative? General or specific? Can they be used as active verbs (Ich verlange die Unterlagen)?

Thanks for any help or suggestions on where to look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*gewünscht* would be the most polite way to say that  like in

> Ich schicke Ihnen die gewünschten Unterlagen

Even if this is not a very literal translation.

If you want to be more literal, use *angefordert* like in

> Ich schicke Ihnen die angeforderten Unterlagen

*gefordert* would be "demanded" (I guess you don't want to express that), but *angefordert* translates directly to "requested"

Comment: For completeness (since *gebetene* was mentioned): *erbetenen* would also work and corresponds to a  very polite response to a polite request. It sounds a bit dated, however.

Answer (score 2):

> Ich schicke Ihnen die gewünschte**n** Unterlagen/Informationen.

Very polite and adequate in almost all situations. Please note that you are talking about the future though this is present tense. If this is a letter and the files are attached you should write

> Anbei die gewünschten Unterlagen/Informationen.

Don't use *angeforderten* or *verlangten* because it turns you into a *tool*. The word *erbetenen* is also okay but a bit old-fashioned. Your other ideas are odd.

---

> Ich schicke Ihnen die Unterlagen/Informationen, die Sie gewünscht haben.
>
> Anbei die …

Also ok but less elaborated code.

Comment: As mentioned above, there is no such word as _*erforderten_. However, in case you're applying for sth (as opposed to responding to a request by the other party), you could also write _die erforderlichen Unterlagen_.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with *angefordert* in my opinion.

Comment: Anbei die gewünschten Unterlagen/Informationen. This sentence doesn't have a verb. Is it implied in "anbei"? The correct usage of this word is new to me. Does one really just stick an anbei phrase at the end of the message?

Comment: It's short for *Ich habe Ihnen die gewünschten Unterlagen/Informationen anbei gegeben.* Though it's short, it's polite.